# What information can a website see if I am using a remote computer?

Tags: remote-desktop, geolocation

Suppose that I have a computer in Australia and access it remotely from Canada. Further suppose the Australian computer isn't used by anyone in Australia -- it's sitting in my locked apartment, left on -- and is only accessed remotely by me.

If I were to log on to a poker site that does not allow customers from Canada, but does allow customers from Australia, would the site be able to trace me back to Canada, or would it appear that I'm logging on from Australia? Assume this site has the best geolocation software presently available.

Comment: how are you "accessing it remotely"?

Comment: Welcome to Security.stackechange. Can you please elaborate your question with some more details, like what do you mean with "accessing it remotely". what OS are you using. what connection do you use?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you are accessing the remote computer. If you are running a remote desktop program, then all web browsing is being initiated by the remote computer, and the target website only knows about the Australian computer.

If you are running a VPN or a proxy on the remote computer, and the web browsing is initiated from Canada, then it is *possible* that the origin computer might leak data to the target. (Search for VPN/proxy privacy leakage on this site and others)